# Getting '$apply is already in progress' error even though I don't explicitly call $apply()

Tags: angularjs

I am creating a directive that helps with uploading a CSV file.  I am using a `<input type="file" ng-hide="true"/>` and the native JavaScript `FileReader()` to do this.  Everything works fine when I select the file using the native `input`, but I tried to customize the file control by using my own "Browse" button. The problem is when I try to do it this way I get the $apply is already in progress error.

Here is my directive

```
app.directive('skUploader', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        template: '<div>\
                    <input type="file" class="uploadControl" ng-hide="false" />\
                    <input type="text" ng-model="selectedFile" />\
                    <button type="button" class="btnPlain" ng-click="triggerBrowse()">Browse</button>\
                    <button type="button" class="btnOrange fRight" ng-click="uploadCSV()">Upload</button>\
                    <button type="button" class="btnPlain fRight" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>\
                   </div>',
        link: function (scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {

            var uploadControl = elem.find('input[type=file]');
            var payload = null;

            var type = attr.skUploader;
            scope.selectedFile = null;

            scope.uploadCSV = function () {
                $timeout(function () {
                    alert('Upload Successful');
                }, 3000);
            }

            scope.cancel = function () {
                payload = null;
                scope.selectedFile = null;
                scope.model.showUploadPanel = false;

            }

            uploadControl.on('change',function () {
                var fileHandle = uploadControl[0].files[0];
                var reader = new FileReader();
                var buffer;

                scope.selectedFile = fileHandle.name;

                reader.onload = function(){
                    buffer = reader.result;

                    payload = parseCSV(buffer);

                    if (payload) {
                        // Make API call
                        if (type == 'mapping') {
                            console.log(payload);
                        } else {

                        }
                    }
                }

                if (fileHandle.name.indexOf('.csv') > 0) {
                    reader.readAsText(fileHandle);
                } else {

                }

                });

            function parseCSV(buff){

                var entries = [];
                entries = buff.split(/\n/);

                var json = [];


                if (type == 'mapping') {
                    var formatter = {
                        iRowNumber: null,
                        SourceName: null,
                        DestName: null
                    };
                } else if (type == 'passwords') {
                    var formatter = {
                        iRowNumber: null,
                        SourceCreds: {
                            EmailAddress: null,
                            Username: null,
                            Pwd: null
                        }
                    };
                } else {
                    return null;
                }


                for(var i = 1; i < entries.length - 1; i++){
                    var split = entries[i].split(',');

                    var obj = angular.copy(formatter);

                    var j = 0;
                    angular.forEach(formatter, function (value, key) {
                        if (key == 'iRowNumber') {
                            obj[key] = i;
                        } else if (key == 'SourceCreds') {
                            obj[key] = {
                                EmailAddress: split[0],
                                Username: split[1],
                                Pwd: split[2]
                            };
                        }else{
                            obj[key] = split[j];
                            j++;
                        }
                    });

                    json.push(obj);

                }

                return json;

            }

            scope.triggerBrowse = function () {
                uploadControl.trigger('click'); // THIS IS WHAT CAUSES THE ERROR
            }
        }
    };
});
```

When I use the "Browse" button to `trigger('click')` the uploadControl, Angular spits out the error

```
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress
```

But I am not using `scope.$apply()` anywhere so I cannot figure out the problem. It should simply trigger the click event on the `<input type="file"/>` which should bring up the OS native file explorer.

**Update**

Could it  be something related to [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4947)?

**Update 2**

After some more research I found [this Git issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1342) that vojta (a core AngularJS dev) responded to saying we need to wrap the event in a `$timeout`. I did this and it actually worked! Could someone please explain to me why this is needed in detail? Thank you

Comment: can you please try with scope.$apply(function(){//wrap fn here which is updating scope})

Comment: Actually when you use $timeout it internally call $apply  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/KFEIbI9C-0Q/p_RLAm6SgPQJ

Comment: Ok but why does using $timeout fix this problem

Comment: because it defers running your code until after any active digest is completed

Comment: $timeout function is wrapped in scope.$apply and $apply call $digest and update the scope..

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When you make changes to the scope without using Angular's functions (using a jQuery click event handler instead of `ngClick`, for example) it gets very grumpy. Sometimes it'll just ignore your changes until it runs another apply, and sometimes you'll catch it at a particularly grumpy moment when it's already busy with other things and it'll give you the error you got.

To be Angular friendly, you need to use its event system to update the scope. If you can't do that, you have a way to tell it you're making changes so that it can deal with those changes on its own schedule. That way is `$timeout` - an Angular-friendly version of JavaScript's `timeout` that is integrated with the update loop. Calling it without a duration parameter just means "The next time you're ready for changes to the scope, do this stuff."

Calling `$apply` yourself is not a good idea, by the way, just use `$timeout`.

Comment: +1 for the use of the correct terminology, "grumpy" :)